# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in

Tags: php, parsing

can you help i'm getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\form-to-email.php on line 42 wondering if you can helpme with this i'm so confused...

```
<?php    {   
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $attend = $_POST['attend'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $office = $_POST['office'];
    $starter = $_POST['starter'];
    $mainmeal = $_POST['mainmeal'];
    $specialdietaryrequirements = $_POST['specialdietaryrequirements'];
    $otherdietaryrequirements = $_POST['otherdietaryrequirements'];
    $nameofguest = $_POST['nameofguest'];
    $starterguest = $_POST['starterguest'];
    $mainmealguest = $_POST['mainmealguest'];
    $guestspecialdietaryrequirements = $_POST['guestspecialdietaryrequirements'];
    $guestotherdietaryrequirements = $_POST['guestotherdietaryrequirements'];
    //email body
    $email_from = 'my@email.com';
    $email_subject = "Christmas Part Submission";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Are you attending: $attend \n".
    "Email address from the person: $email \n".
    "Contact number: $phone \n".
    "Office: $office \n".
    "Starter: $starter \n".
    "Main Meal: $mainmeal \n".
    "Special Dietary Requirements: $specialdietaryrequirements \n".
    "Other Dietary Requirements: $otherdietaryrequirements \n".
    "Name of Guest: $nameofguest \n".
    "Guest Starter: $starterguest \n".
    "Guest Main Meal: $mainmealguest \n".
    "Guest Special Dietary requirements: $guestspecialdietaryrequirements \n".
    "Guest other Dietary requirements: $guestotherdietaryrequirements \n".
    // who it is being sent too (edit this)
    $to = "my@email.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    {   ?>
```

Comment: Missing `;` at the ned of line `"Guest other Dietary requirements: $guestotherdietaryrequirements \n".`

Comment: line 42...  replace `{` with `}`

Comment: Also remove the `.` at that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<?php    {   
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
```

with

```
<?php  
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
```

and the `{` at the very end of your long code should be `}`

Comment: Brilliant it works now all i get is a blank page and it won't send to email. Than kyou for your help

Comment: Do you have your correct email for this line? $to = "my@email.com";

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you forgot to close your if statement and whatever came before that.
 Try replacing

```
{
```

at the end of your file with

```
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last opening curly bracket at the end has to be changed to a closing one

Answer (score 0):

first line only

```
<?php
```

no {

last line:
you must close the IF tag not open it!

}

```
<?php       
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    ...
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    }   
?>
```